# How to add user dictionary with StanfordCoreNLP

Tags: java, python, stanford-nlp

I am currently using StanfordCoreNLP to do word tokenization in Chinese. 
I've currently already managed to run the tokenizer with python:

```
>>> from stanfordcorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP
>>> nlp = StanfordCoreNLP(r'D:/Yihua/FYP/Codes/stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05', lang = 'zh')
>>> abc = '今天天气不错啊，很适合去游泳呢'
>>> nlp.word_tokenize(abc)
['今天', '天气', '不错', '啊', '，', '很', '适合', '去', '游泳', '呢']
```

However now I want to add my own dictionary to improve the tokenization result. For example I want '很适合' as a single token. (I actually have a list of words as my own dict). How should I do to add the dictionary?

---

I've already know that the dict file lies in the .jar file:

#### stanford-chinese-corenlp-2018-10-05-models.jar\edu\stanford\nlp\models\segmenter\chinese\dict-chris6.ser.gz

But how can i modify it since i opened it with notepad++ and then it turns out to be messy codes.

Comment: Are you familar with [Using Stanford CoreNLP on other human languages](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/human-languages.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is info here about building your own dictionary:

https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/segmenter-faq.html

You can include our dictionary in the list of files and a list of your own custom files.